# Sorting nearly sorted array with O(n*Log(K)) complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Problem -Nearly Sorted Array- Given an array of n elements , each of which is atmost K Position away from it's actual position in the sorted array , devise an algorithm that sorts in O(nLogK) time.

```
Approach - I divide the array in n/K elements each(n/k + 1 , if n%k!=0).

Then I run a loop n/k times ,inside which I sort eack n/k group using 
MergeSort(Complexity = KLogK).So complexity for the loop is O(nLogK).

Finally I merge the n/k groups using a Merge Function(similar to Merging 
K Sorted arrays, complexity = nLog(n/k)).

So overall complexity is between nLogK and nLog(n/K) but I have to 
achieve complexity O(nLogK).
Comparing K and n/K depends on values of n and K.
```

Can anyone help me with the final merging operation or a better approach.

PS : I do not know heaps or queues at the time so I am looking for a solution which does not involve these.

Comment: i'm actually not sure, if merge-sort is the right approach here, maybe it's better to use some variation of bubble-sort, since bubble sort performs better, if input is already nearly sorted, like in your example

Comment: Insertion sort is an option but with greater complexity

Comment: well, insertion sort has better performance if the input is nearly sorted, in best case(input is fully sorted) it's complexity is O(n)

Comment: If using only insertion sort the complexity will be O(nk)

Comment: I don't tell you to use insert-sort instead of merge-sort, I tell you to overthink your whole algorithm and make it like a insert-sort with slightly modification

Comment: Consider a radically different algorithm, with an ancillary heap of size `k`.

Answer (score 5):

First, divide the array into groups of at least `k+1` elements. So that each element's rightful position is either within the group where the element currently is or within the group to the left or to the right, but not further. Then sort each group.

This step takes `O((n/k) * k log k) = O(n log k)`.

Then, after sorting each group, you can merge `i`th group with the `i+1` group, for `i` from `1` to `n/(k+1) - 1`.

By merge I understand the merge procedure from a merge sort. The groups do not unite. Their sizes remain the same.

Each merge takes `O(n/k)`, in total this step is `O(n)`.

Comment: somehow i don't understand your merge, do you merge all groups into 1 big result? if so, you would need more time for every consecutive merge...

Comment: @JohnnyAW You only have to merge each group with its direct neighbours. That's because even before sorting each group, each element is at most k-elements away from its proper position.

Comment: Ok, I've just noticed that my method requires that each element is at most k-1 positions away. But that's fine we can divide the array into slightly larger groups n/(k+1) elements each.

Comment: wait, I think we would get 4 arrays with length 3 each for merge: [1,2,4][2,4,5][2,3,5][3,5,6] but still, after final merge we get 3 arrays with length 6?

Comment: n = 9, k = 2: [1,4,2,5,3,8,9,6,7] => [1,2,4][3,5,8][6,7,9] => [1,2,3][4,5,8][6,7,9] => [1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]

Comment: The last two steps are merge group 1 with 2, and merge group 2 with 3

Comment: @JohnnyAW, basically the merges just move the elements between the groups, but leave the groups' boundaries as they are.

Comment: @ciamej Merging that way , the work done would be like 2k + 3k + 4k .. which will not be linear. It will turn out to be O(n^2 /K)

Comment: @ciamej the second step doesn't make sense: [1,4,2,5,3,8,9,6,7] => [1,2,4][3,5,8][6,7,9] =>(I don't think you can merge like this...) [1,2,3][4,5,8][6,7,9] => [1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]

Comment: @JohnnyAW Why is that? You take [4,5,8] and [6,7,9] merge it to [4,5,6,7,8,9] and leave it as it is [4,5,6][7,8,9]. The boundaries between groups are only imaginatory...

Comment: @JohnnyAW if it's easier for you to understand, then each merge is followed by a split in half. This split is a no-op in reality.

Comment: @ArmaanChugh no, each step is `O(k)` you always take two groups of the same size. In my example the size is 3. The size of groups does not increase with each merge. The groups remain the same size.

Comment: @ciamej ok, I think I understand the merge, but what if n=8? do you have overlapping groups?

Comment: @JohnnyAW if the `n%(k+1) != 0` then the last group can be smaller.

Comment: @ciamej wait, but then your merge complexity would be O(2*n/(k+1)) and not O(n/k)

Comment: @JohnnyAW Each merge takes `O(2 * (k+1)) = O(k)` steps. There is exactly `floor(n / (k+1))` merges, which gives us a total of `O(floor(n / (k+1)) * k) = O(n)` steps.

Comment: @ciamej oh, right, merge is O(2k), but you can't simplify it to O(k) so in the end you get O(n/k*2*k) = O(2n)

Comment: @JohnnyAW `O(2k) = O(k)` by definition.

Comment: @ciamej ok, I think I got it now :D

Comment: @ciamej why do you specify dividing the array into groups of at least k+1 elements? Why not k?

Comment: @JashShah Honestly, I don't remember! When I think about it now, I think I made an error. Groups of size k should be fine.